# Can't access unprotected .pst file in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

My father has a Windows 7 x64 system with 32-bit Outlook 2010. He asked me to access his archived mail to get to some old mail. When going to open the file I'm asked for a password (he never applied one) and I get a message saying "password is incorrect. Re-Type password". Since he told me that he never set a password I tried opening the .pst with Nucleus, a tool that allows me to view the .pst's. Does anyone know what the deal is? With the free version of Nucleus we can't view the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recovering the password using [PstPassword](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/pst_password.html) tool.